# Как сделать выбор в списке select

Tags: javascript, onchange

Кусочек кода:

```html
<select id="select_status" onchange="selectStatus;">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">Первый</option>
  <option value="2">Второй</option>
  <option value="3">Третий</option>
  <option value="4">Четвертый</option>
</select>
```

Как с помощью javascript выбрать, например третий вариант? Пробовал всяко-разно, изменения происходит на странице, а в коде нет, по итогу после обновления страницы все сбрасывается. Наверно, надо как то использовать onchange?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Свойство `selectedIndex`, указывает на номер выбранной опции (считая с нуля)

```js
document.querySelector("#select_status").selectedIndex = 2;
```

```html
<select id="select_status">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">Первый</option>
  <option value="2">Второй</option>
  <option value="3">Третий</option>
  <option value="4">Четвертый</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Пробовал этот вариант, не работает, он меняет значение на странице, но при обновлении данных происходит сброс на то значение, которое стояло до этого, в коде при том ничего не меняется, если кликать мышью то код меняется и значение сохраняется))

Comment: @Влад О_о а в вопросе ничего не было про обновление данных... Тогда надо знать, как именно они обновляются и откуда. Смотреть-разбираться, что делает обновляющая функция.

Comment: Как это не было, все там есть!))

Comment: И дело даже не в обновлении страницы, а именно в обновлении данных на странице, они там автоматически подгружаются по таймингу, все вот такие подобные решения я попробовал, изменения есть, сохранения нет, вот думаю в сторону onchange, но как его использовать не понятно....

Comment: @Влад onchange гарантированно не сработает (он запускается при изменении опции, а не при вставке новых), надо найти таймер, который запускает обновления, и внести изменения там: Выбрать опцию сразу после обновления (onload ?). Если всё никак, можно методом тыка пробовать нащупать через [MutationObserver](https://jsfiddle.net/64gtus28/1)